# Python subploting

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to produce a subplot using the following code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplot(3, 2)
axes[0, 0].pcolor(dataset_one[0], dataset_one[1], dataset_two[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
axes[0, 0].set_title('Raw Scattering Data along (4, K, 0)')
axes[1, 0].pcolor(dataset_two[0], dataset_two[1], dataset_two[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
axes[1, 0].set_title('Raw Scattering Data along (H, 4, 0)')
axes[2, 0].pcolor(dataset_three[0], dataset_three[1], dataset_three[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
axes[2, 0].set_title('Raw Scattering Data along (4, 0, L)')
axes[0, 1].pcolor(dataset_one_subtracted[0], dataset_one_subtracted[1], dataset_one_subtracted[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
axes[1, 1].pcolor(dataset_two_subtracted[0], dataset_two_subtracted[1], dataset_two_subtracted[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
axes[2, 1].pcolor(dataset_three_subtracted[0], dataset_three_subtracted[1], dataset_three_subtracted[2], cmap='jet', vmin=-100, vmax=10000)
fig.xlabel('Momentum Transfer (r.l.u)')
fig.ylabel('Energy Transfer (meV)')
fig.title('Neutron Scattering Data for Lead Magnesium Niobate (PMN)')
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "subplots_E_vs_Q.py", line 257, in <module>
        fig, axes = plt.subplot(3, 2)
    File "/home/s1406403/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1072, in subplot
        a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/s1406403/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1239, in add_subplot
        a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/s1406403/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 72, in __init__
        raise ValueError('Illegal argument(s) to subplot: %s' % (args,))
        ValueError: Illegal argument(s) to subplot: (3, 2)
```

And after looking through the documentation and other tutorials I am still not sure what is the problem with the code and especially the arguments.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplot-demo-py ... [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) ... [`plt,subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html?highlight=subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be `plt.subplots(3,2)` with an extra `s`

Comment: You believe or it is?